# Cannot Access Restructured Array Passed to jQuery from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to reconstruct an array of objects to group objects with an equivalent key together to pass to a jQuery function. Currently, I have an array like this:

```
$myOldArr =

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [class] => atest
            [name] => atestvar1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [class] => btest
            [name] => btestvar1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [class] => btest
            [name] => btestvar2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [class] => ctest
            [name] => ctestvar1
        )
)
```

And I transform it into this grouped based on the "class" key in the above array.

```
$myNewArr =

Array
(
    [atest] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [class] => atest
                    [name] => atestvar1
                )

        )

    [btest] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [class] => btest
                    [name] => btestvar1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [class] => btest
                    [name] => btestvar2
                )

        )

    [ctest] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [class] => ctest
                    [name] => ctestvar1
                )

        )
)
```

My goal is to pass this reconstructed array so that I can dynamically create some DOMs based on the number of objects under each "class". However, when I pass part of the new array in php to jQuery

```
foreach (array_keys($myNewArr) as $item) {
?>
    <div onclick="myjQueryFcn(<?php echo json_encode($myNewArr[$item]); ?>)></div>
<?php
}
```

jQuery fails to execute the function. If I do not `json_encode` the array, jQuery detects a function as sent for the argument.

The encoding shows that I'm getting, for example, the following json object for `$myNewArr[$item="btest"]`:

```
[{"id":"6","class":"btest","name":"btestvar1"},{"id":"7","class":"btest","name":"btestvar2"}]
```

myjQueryFcn is simply alerting the output currently.

```
function myjQueryFcn(json) {
    alert(typeof json);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the structure of my new array? I've been struggling with this and for all the searching I've done and solutions I've tried, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is the quoting: your json string contains double quotes, which break the onclick="..." quoting.

you can either use

```
onclick='...'
```

or use html entities within your string:

```
onclick="myjQuerFcn([{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;btest&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;btestvar1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;btest&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;btestvar2&quot;}])"
```

which is also ugly.

You can also create a javascript variable from within your script first:

```
<script>
var obj = '<?php json_encode($myNewArr[$item="btest"]); ?>'
</script>
<div onclick="myjQueryFcn(obj);"></div>
```

Not to mention that this is not the fine art of programming...

A better solution is to fetch your (json) data using ajax, but this need some more infrastructure:

```
// java script part:
$.getJSON('php-script.php', function(data){
   $.each(data,function(index,entry) {
       var div = $('<div></div>').on('click', function() {
          alert(entry); // [Object]
       }
       $(document).append(div);
   });
});
```

--

```
<?php
// php-script.php:
echo json_encode($myNewArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alex. I'm not even sure I would have ever discovered that on my own. Seems like a strange circumstance given the recommendations for using JSON to pass PHP objects. Is there a more appropriate approach to encoding/passing objects? JSON by standard is supposed to be double-quoted, while I'm trying to adhere to xhtml standards as well. Your last solution just seems sloppy, especially given that this will probably be re-used in multiple locations...

Comment: The recommendation to use JSON when passing PHP object is meant if you load the data from a backend using a HTTP request - but in your case you are generating the data within the page itself, which is not very nice, anyway. you COULD load your data using an ajax request asynchronously, for example.

Comment: Just updated the entry above, added an AJAX example, fetching your data asynchronously from the server. Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess right now I have the data pulling from the mySQL database using a PHP Class. I COULD change it to pull directly from the JS side, but then I'd be making duplicate calls to the db in one page.

Comment: No, you get me wrong: The DB logic remains on the backend - in your case the PHP part - you only fetch the data from the frontend (javascript) from your server separately, instead of generating one html file containing everything - you separate the view (the html/js) from the data (the php).

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right. Currently, I'm accessing the DB data by instantiating a PHP Class in an HTML page and then passing that data through events (such as `onclick=""`) to my JS. You're suggesting to call a PHP function using e.g., $.ajax() in jQuery when I need to access server data instead? So instead of having a bunch of PHP Classes that I load up on each HTML page, I'd be better with a bunch of php function scripts to call from JS that essentially contain this functionality? Sorry if I'm off, I really want to hammer this out before I go further with my learning.